# How to do inverse overlay on google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

I want to develop the above picture in android, which is already implemented in iOS.

I know how to add circle on google map. but **as shown in picture the color should be filled on map not on the circle, circle must be fully transparent**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve what you want by using the google MapView (instead of a Map fragment) and adding another image on top of this map view.

having said that, do note that what you want is against the google maps usage terms and services.
(https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

> 8.4 b. Restrictions. In using Google Brand Features, you will not:
>
> viii remove, distort, or alter any element of a Google Brand Feature (including squeezing, stretching, inverting, or discoloring).
>
> 8.5 Proprietary Rights Notices. You will not remove, obscure, or alter any proprietary rights notices (including copyright and trademark notices, Terms of Use links, or Brand Features) displayed or provided through the Service. Where such notices are not displayed or provided within the Service, you must display such notices according to the Maps APIs Documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I have a good solution for your problem.

You can use an image which has a transparent circular area in the middle.  Overlay the image on the map by using Relative Layout or FrameLayout.
That overlay will result in the map showing only in the middle circle.

Comment: what happen when user will use zoom in zoom out on map...??

Comment: Nothing , Its work as by defult. Your image statically on Layout. S you have not  problem in zoom in zoom out.

Comment: sorry brother, its not working :(
how static image of circle will change its size when user zoom in or zoom out the map. :(